# A more complex solution maybe!

Tags: trigonometry, complex-numbers

Prove that

$\sin(\theta) + \sin(\theta+2\pi/3) + \sin(\theta+4\pi/3) = 0 $

I was able to solve it using trigonometric identities but I want a method which uses complex numbers.

Any help would be appreciated.